# Equivalent to git difftool -y with libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am planning to replace the usage of `git.exe` from windows path by `libgit2sharp` for my plugin `GitDiffMargin`, A Visual Studio 2012 extension to display Git Diff on the margin of the current file. - https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin

I would like to know if there is an equivalent in `libgit2sharp` to start the external difftool using `git difftool -y filename` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it should be the responsibility of LibGit2Sharp to launch an external process. LibGit2Sharp goal is to provide a way to manipulate a git repository easily.

It means you can use it to:

- Get the diff between files in the workdir and the previous version (in the index). To do that you can use the `Repository.Diff.Compare(IEnumerable<string> paths, bool includeUntracked, ExplicitPathsOptions explicitPathsOptions)` overload, which returns a `TreeChanges` object. From there, you can get a `TreeEntryChanges` object through the indexer of the treeChanges, which corresponds to the changes of a given file (use the .Patch property to get the actual content of the patch).
- Get the configured diff tool by using the `Repository.Config` namespace (e.g.: `repo.Config.Get<string>("diff.tool").Value`, although you should also check if the value returned by the `Get()` method is null in case no diff tool has been configured by the user). That way, you can launch the diff tool by yourself.

Additional resources (v0.11.0):

- Diff workdir to index [tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/v0.11.0/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffWorkdirToIndexFixture.cs)
- An [example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/v0.11.0/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs#L47-L70) showing how to use the `TreeChanges` object
- [Configuration fixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/v0.11.0/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ConfigurationFixture.cs), pretty self-explanatory

---

**Note**: it seems that at some point, you will need to know if a line has changed or not. I don't think there is an easy way to do that right now (apart from parsing the patch content manually). However, opening an issue on the LibGit2Sharp [issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues) might trigger some discussion around that (feel free to weigh in what kind of API you would like to have to do that!).

---

**Edit**: Before launching the external diff tool, you will need to copy the content of the file which is in the index in a temporary folder. You can lookup the blob of a file in the index by doing something like:

- var indexEntry = repo.Index[fileName];
- var blob = repo.Lookup(indexEntry.Id);

However... no filters are currently applied when you get the blob content, so the comparison is likely to produce false positives due to crlf differences.
There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1264) opened on libgit2 in order to propose an API to allow applying filters.

Comment: Thanks yorah! In the meantime I found about Repository.Config and will have a more details look at it!
Concerning the line changes I already have something which is parsing the diff but I am just waiting to have this changes https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/423